# Concatenating multiple character elements from variable and recoding as 0 and 1

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create two new variables out of a long list of elements AND recode them as 0 and 1 to run in a logistic regression. That is, the OS1 variable in the survey indicates the operating system on which the respondent completed the survey. I would like to recode those that are mobile as "mobile" and those on a pc as "pc". I tried using the dplyr::case_when(), but didn't seem to behave like the other variables, which I didn't have to sub-categorize. My goal is to do this in the piping operator I show below.

As an example, I show how I filtered Campus A and incentive type. And then how I created three new variable columns (finished, grade, and incentive) using dplyr::case_when().

```
survey <- seru %>% 
select(FINISHED, WC001_INCENTIVE, LEVEL, OS1, CAMPUS_Supplemental) %>%
filter(CAMPUS_Supplemental == "Campus") %>%
filter(WC001_INCENTIVE %in% c("A chance to win one of ten $100 Visa   
gift cards", "A chance to win one of three $500 Visa gift cards",
     "I wanted my opinions to be heard by faculty, staff, and 
the administration")) %>%
mutate(finished = factor(dplyr::case_when(
FINISHED  == "0" ~ 0,
FINISHED == "1" ~ 1
), levels = c(0:1), labels = c("No", "Yes"))) %>%
mutate(grade = factor(dplyr::case_when(
LEVEL == "Freshman" ~ 0,
LEVEL == "Sophomore" ~ 1, 
LEVEL == "Junior" ~ 2,
LEVEL == "Senior" ~ 3
), levels = c(0:3), labels = c("freshman", "sophomore", "junior",     
"senior"))) %>%
mutate(incentive = factor(dplyr::case_when(
WC001_INCENTIVE == "A chance to win one of ten $100 Visa gift cards" ~ 
0, WC001_INCENTIVE == "A chance to win one of three $500 Visa gift  
cards" ~ 1,
WC001_INCENTIVE == "I wanted my opinions to be heard by 
faculty, staff, and the administration" ~ 2
), levels = c(0:2), labels = c("$100 gift card", "$500 gift card", 
"Opinion heard")))
```

Here is the data frame's structure. Again, I mutated FINISHED, LEVEL, and WC001_INCENTIVE into new variables ("finished", "grade", and "incentive").

```
 str(survey)
 'data.frame':  4999 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ FINISHED           : int  1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 ...

 $ WC001_INCENTIVE    : Factor w/ 6 levels " ","  Strongly agree",..: 4 
   4 4 4 4 3 5 5 4 4 ...
 $ LEVEL              : Factor w/ 5 levels "","Freshman",..: 3 2 5 2 4 
    2 5 2 5 2 ...
 $ OS1                : Factor w/ 44 levels " ","Android 4.1.2",..: 12 
    37 34 31 40 31 12 37 37 31 ...

 $ CAMPUS_Supplemental: Factor w/ 5 levels "","Campus A","Campus B",..: 
   3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...

 $ finished  : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2    
   1 ...

 $ grade  : Factor w/ 4 levels "freshman","sophomore",..: 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 
    1 2 1 ...

 $ incentive : Factor w/ 3 levels "$100 gift card",..: 2 2 2 2 
     2 1 3 3 2 2 ...
```

So like I did with "incentive" and "grade", I want to create two new variables, "mobile" and "pc" as sub-variables to OS1- That is, amalgamate all the mobile operating systems into one variable and pc operating systems into another. I looked at other threads, but they all point to creating the variable using the c() function. I need mine to be a sub-variable of OS1, so would like to include this is in the piping operator above.

Mobile:

```
 c("iPhone", 'Windows Phone 10.0", "Windows Phone 8.1",   
 "Android 4.1.2", "Android 4.3", "Android 4.4.2", "Android 4.4.4",    
 "Android 5.0", "Android 5.0.1", "Android 5.0.2", "Android 5.1", 
 "Android 5.1.1", "Android 6.0", "Android 6.0.1", "Android 7.0", 
 "Android 7.1.1", "Android 7.1.2")
```

Pc:

```
"Windows NT 10.0", "Windows NT 5.1", "Windows NT 6.0", "Windows NT 
6.1", "Windows NT 6.2", "Windows NT 6.3", "Macintosh"
```

The end goal is to do a logistic regression, where OS1 has two levels: mobile and pc. That is, did operating system (using your phone or personal computer) influence whether or not the respondent finished the survey.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This will create two new columns `mobile` and `pc` coded as TRUE/FALSE:

```
library(tidyverse)

MobileOS <- c("iPhone", "Windows Phone 10.0", "Windows Phone 8.1",
              "Android 4.1.2", "Android 4.3", "Android 4.4.2", "Android 4.4.4",    
              "Android 5.0", "Android 5.0.1", "Android 5.0.2", "Android 5.1", 
              "Android 5.1.1", "Android 6.0", "Android 6.0.1", "Android 7.0", 
              "Android 7.1.1", "Android 7.1.2")

PCOS <- c("Windows NT 10.0", "Windows NT 5.1", "Windows NT 6.0", "Windows NT 6.1", 
          "Windows NT 6.2", "Windows NT 6.3", "Macintosh")

seru %>%
  mutate(mobile = OS1 %in% MobileOS,
         pc = OS1 %in% PCOS)
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me try this out.

Comment: So when I ran this, I first selected "mobile." The intercept 1.8 and mobileTRUE -0.79. I then ran it again with "pc". Intercept 1.08 and pcTRUE .79. That is, they're the same values, one negative one positive. Is this right?

Comment: That makes sense if mobile & pc are the only operating systems and every record is either one or the other.  In a situation like that, you really only need one of them in your model, since every case of mobile = TRUE is also a case where pc = FALSE and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks. I was unsure since the intercepts were different, but coefficients the same in absolute terms. But it would make sense since there's only two possible values, pc or mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just solve your problem with the powerfully underrated `%in%` command, like so:

```
mobile <- c("iPhone", 
            "Windows Phone 10.0", "Windows Phone 8.1", 
            "Android 4.1.2", "Android 4.3", "Android 4.4.2", "Android 4.4.4", 
            "Android 5.0", "Android 5.0.1", "Android 5.0.2", "Android 5.1", "Android 5.1.1", 
            "Android 6.0", "Android 6.0.1", 
            "Android 7.0", "Android 7.1.1", "Android 7.1.2")

pc <- c("Windows NT 10.0", "Windows NT 5.1", 
        "Windows NT 6.0", "Windows NT 6.1", "Windows NT 6.2", "Windows NT 6.3", 
        "Macintosh")

os <- c(mobile, pc)

newos <- ifelse(os %in% mobile, "mobile", ifelse(os %in% pc, "pc", NA))
```

EDIT: mine is basically a base-R version of what Jordo82 did, above.

Comment: Thanks! I've never seen it done that way. I'll try this out too.